# How to Retrieve 10 first Google Search Results Using Python Requests

Tags: python, google-api, urllib, google-search-api

I've seen lots of questions regarding this subject and i found out that Google has been updating the way its search engine APIs work.

This link > [get the first 10 google results using googleapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441812/get-the-first-10-google-results-using-googleapi) shows EXACTLY what I need but the thing is I don't know if it's possible to do that anymore.

I need this to my term paper but by reading Google docs I couldn't find a way to do that.
I've done the "get started" stuff and all I got was a private search engine using custom search engine (CSE).

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use Python, Selenium and PhantomJS or other browsers to browse through Google's search results and grab the content. I haven't done that personally and don't know if there are challenges there.

I believe the best way would be to use their search APIs. Please try the one you pointed out. If it doesn't work, look for the new APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm going to take a look at selenium and try to use Yahoo! In the worst case scenario.

Comment: You may upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Already upvoted, just disnt accept because it didnt actually solve the problem, the upvote cant be seen because i dont have 15 pointsnyet, but tou owned it 

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question while trying to solve this problem myself and I found an updated solution to this.

Basically I used this guide at [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest#standard_query_parameters) to generate my own api key and search engine, then use python requests to retrieve the json results.

```
def search(query):
    api_key = 'MYAPIKEY'
    search_engine_id = 'MYENGINEID'
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1/siterestrict?key=%s&cx=%s&q=%s" % (api_key, search_engine_id, query)
    result = requests.Session().get(url)
    json = simplejson.loads(result.content)
    return json
```